# Why does SQL Server 2008 R2 insert an invalid datetime when using bulk insert?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, datetime, bulk-insert

I want to insert rows with an optional datetime value (per row) using [T-SQL BULK INSERT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
on a SQL Server 2008 R2.

A table could look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_bulk_insert_datetime_issue] (
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [description] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [datetime] [datetime] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [pk_bulk_insert_datetime_issue] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
    [id] ASC
))
```

The insert batch:

```
BULK
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_bulk_insert_datetime_issue]
FROM 'C:\temp\bulkinsertsample.csv'
WITH
(
    FIELDTERMINATOR=';'
)
```

If I am to insert the following CSV content:

```
1;row01;
2;row02;20130401
3;row03;
4;row04;20130515
```

The table' content was parsed and inserted as expected:

```
id          description          datetime
----------- -------------------- -----------------------
1           row01                NULL
2           row02                2013-04-01 00:00:00.000
3           row03                NULL
4           row04                2013-05-15 00:00:00.000
```

---

But if the CSV file contains invalid data for the optional datetime

```
1;row01;
2;row02;20130401
3;row03;not_a_datetime
4;row04;20130515
```

SQL Server inserts the last valid datetime value instead of discarding the row with an error message:

```
id          description          datetime
----------- -------------------- -----------------------
1           row01                NULL
2           row02                2013-04-01 00:00:00.000
3           row03                2013-04-01 00:00:00.000
4           row04                2013-05-15 00:00:00.000
```

If I am to insert a row with an invalid datetime and no valid parsable datetime at all

```
1;row01;not_a_datetime
```

SQL Server inserts the **default value** of [DATETIME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
id          description          datetime
----------- -------------------- -----------------------
1           row01                1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

Why does Sql Server insert the (for that specific row) invalid datetime when using bulk insert?
If I try to insert rubbish to an INT column the row will not be inserted by the bulk batch and an error will be thrown...

---

**UPDATE:**
I will share some information about the environment I used to reproduce the behaviour.

- OS: Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 x64
- regional settings: de-DE
- Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2500.0 (X64) Enterprise Edition
- database collation: Latin1_General_100_CS_AS
- file encoding: UCS-2 Little Endian (with Windows CRLF)

As hinted by [Max Vernon](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/52764/30148) the file encoding seems to be at fault. Setting the encoding to UTF-8 without BOM the bulk insert will throw the error I expected and discards the invalid row.

Comment: Wow, this is interesting, smells like a bug to me.

Comment: Can you share what your ANSI options for your SSMS session are set to when you execute this?

Comment: @MikeFal following are checked: QUOTED_IDENTIFIER, ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON, ANSI_PADDING, ANSI_WARNINGS, ANSI_NULLS
- How do these settings influence the behaviour of a bulk insert?

Comment: @AaronBertrand As suggested I have addressed a bug here:
https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/807767/sql-server-2008-r2-insert-an-invalid-datetime-when-using-bulk-insert-from-a-csv-file-with-encoding-ucs-2-little-endian

Answer (score 4):

On SQL Server 2005, and SQL Server 2012, I did the following:

```
USE tempdb;
CREATE TABLE ImpTest
(
    ImpTestID INT NULL
    , ImpTestDate DATETIME NULL
);
GO
BULK INSERT ImpTest FROM 'C:\SQLServer\ImportTest.txt' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR=',');
SELECT * FROM ImpTest;
DROP TABLE ImpTest;
```

With the following data:

```
1,
2,20130406
3,NOT_DATE
4,
5,20130409
```

On both servers, I received the following:

```
Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified
codepage) for row 3, column 2 (ImpTestDate).
```

Perhaps, as Aaron noted, this is a bug that needs to be addressed through http://connect.microsoft.com

I'm wondering about some of the details of your system, including locale settings, collations, physical format of the import file (is it from a Unix system? etc).

Comment: The physical file was the hint I needed... For interest: I could reproduce the behaviour on a Sql Server 2005 with file encoding UCS-2 Little Endian and collation set to Latin1_General_CI_AS - the row with the invalid data was inserted with the wrong datetime. But setting the file encoding to UTF-8 without BOM threw the error I expected and the row was not inserted.

Answer (score -2):

Think outside the box.  Ask yourself why you are holding the data in the first place.  What is the database for?  Well, holding data of course! But why, what is its use?  It’s to make data available to reports or to a front end.  In that sense, it doesn’t matter whether a date is held in a date or a character field.  I’ve seen solutions offered which say to import to a staging table and then run scripts to transfer and convert the data to the final destination.  Why?  Just import the data and then, if you must, create a view which does the conversion.  Make the view rather than the table available to reports or front end processes.  From a security point of view, that is probably best practise anyway.
Simple Example:

```
CREATE TABLE t_Input
    (
    StartDate VARCHAR(50),
    EndDate VARCHAR(50)
    )
GO
CREATE VIEW vw_Output
AS
    SELECT
        StartDate = CONVERT(datetime, StartDate, 101),
        EndDate = CONVERT(datetime, EndDate, 101)
    FROM
        t_Input
```

Then make the view available to the BI or Front end developers rather than the base table.

Comment: I fail to see how this answers the question.